# decrement int from string time 4:01 to 3:51 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, notifications, uilocalnotification

hi I want to make a local notification from string time, I want the notification launch 10 minute before given time. I have trouble how to make the time from 4:01 into 3:51, please help. this is my code

```
let a = "4:01"

func startNoftification(prayer: String) {
    let time = prayer.split(separator: ":").map { (x) -> Int in
    return Int(String(x))!
}
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "Adzan"
   content.body = "it's time to sholat dzuhur"

   let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
   var component = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
   component.hour = time[0]
   component.minute = time[1] - 10

   guard let date = gregorian.date(from: component) else { return }
   let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Hijrah", content: content, trigger: trigger)

   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("Notif error:", err)
        return
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
let time = "4:01"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time) else {
    return 
} 

let targetTime = Date(timeInterval: -(10 * 60), since: date) // Change time interval to required value in seconds
let targetTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: targetTime)
print(targetTimeString) // Prints 3:51
```

Or if your countdown time has a lot of time components, use `DateComponents`.

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.minute = -10
// Other components

if let targetTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date)
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: targetTime))
}
```

Comment: your code is work, now my problem is how to setup in user notification. thank your for your reply

Comment: @ferryawijayanto that should be asked as a separate question. You current question did include that.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear enough, but I will try using your code to setup local notification.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have solution combine with rakesha Shastri answer, hopefully it can helps others.

First import UserNotification in appDelegate and in your controller

```
import UserNotification
```

and add code for didFinishWithLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Notifications permission denied because:", err)
            return
        }

        if granted {
            print("Notifications permission granted.")
        }
    }
}
```

and you can make a function and add string time parameters either from API or arbitrary string, since I'm not using function so I pass my solution in viewDidLoad

```
let adzan = "4:01"

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Adzan"
    content.body = "It's time for sholat"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    // Format the date first from string time
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    //addingTimeInterval is where you want to set notification before or after deciding time in this case I set it 10 minute before deciding time
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: adzan)?.addingTimeInterval(-600) else { return }

    // and convert our date into dateComponents
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```